# Backup - Restore process of a Site Collection in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created one site collection on Office 365 which was like development environment. Now I want to make another site collection with the content same as development site. So can anyone explain me how to go about backup and restore of site collection in SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Online, we cannot backup and restore contents as what we do in SharePoint Server 2013. Instead, the backup and restoring features are reflected by the following features: version, template, recycle bin and some third party solutions.

You can save a web as a template  but  these are low fidelity duplication tools rather than a backup tool.

Please follow this links to get more information about backup process in SharePoint Online

https://itsolutionsblog.net/the-backup-options-in-sharepoint-online/

http://www.threewill.com/the-4-options-you-need-to-know-about-sharepoint-online-backup-and-restore/